# Weird behavior of a counter inside the for loop

Tags: c

I've noticed that a counter(`a`variable) of the for loop, doesn't works well.
Indeed, the counter doesn't decrements correctly; I know this question seems stupid , but I can't understand why the `a` variable does this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,i,b,matrice[2][2];
    printf("Put inside the matrix some numbers..\n");


    for (a=2;a>=0;a--) {
        for (b=2;b>=0;b--) {
            matrice[a][b]=scanf("%d",&i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell me how many times the innermost line will run and how many elements the matrix has.

Comment: Change to `for (a=1;a>=0;a--) {`. You're starting out ouf bounds.

Comment: The `for (a=2;a>=0;a--)` is not the only issue.. Similar fix for `for (b=2;b>=0;b--)`. Also `matrice[a][b]=scanf("%d",&i);` has syntax problems.. look to my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The array index start from 0, as per your code it will access `matrice[2][2]` which will cause **undefined behavior**.

2) `matrice[a][b]=scanf("%d",&i);` will store the return value of `scanf` in `matrice[a][b]`.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,b,matrice[2][2];
    printf("Put inside the matrix some numbers..\n");


    for (a=1;a>=0;a--) 
    {
        for (b=1;b>=0;b--) 
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrice[a][b]);
        }
    }
    //Then print or do other operations on matrice
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!! Indeed, i was thinking that the problem may be an oversight

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to read the numbers into the matrix, then this is what you are supposed to do..

```
for (a=1;a>=0;a--) {
    for (b=1;b>=0;b--) {
        scanf("%d",&matrice[a][b]);
    }
```

As the array `matrice[2][2]` has `2*2` elements, the valid indices are `0` and `1`.
Thats why the `for` loop should start from `1` and not `2`

Answer (score 1):

You are going out of bounds when you read into your array.

```
for (a=2;a>=0;a--) {
```

Array has only two elements, yet you try to read into the third on the first iteration.

```
matrice[2]
```

Is the third element. This happens for both dimensions.

scanf() call is not correct. It reads the value into `i`, but it returns the number of read items, not the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix has a size of `[2][2]` but you are using a loop that runs from 2 to 0 (inclusive). In an array of size 2 the maximum permissible index is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting out of bounds.

For an array of size `n` you iterate from `0` to `n-1`

So what you want is

```
for (a=1;a>=0;a--){
    for (b=1;b>=0;b--){

    }
}
```

But one word of warning with running backwards with for loops. As is you are fine because you are using integers but if you were to do something like this

```
for (auto i = some_vector.size()-1;i>=0;i--){

}
```

You would be in a lot of trouble since i would not be able to take negative values as `some_vector.size()` is of type `unsigned` so the loop would never exit. I tend to always increment in a  loop for this reason unless the logic dictates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are just learning basic stuff.. so try to run this slightly version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a,i,b,matrice[2][2];
    printf("Put inside the matrix some numbers..\n");

    for (a=1;a>=0;a--) {
        printf("a->%d\n", a);
        for (b=1;b>=0;b--) {
            printf(" b->%d\n", b);
            scanf("%d",&matrice[a][b]);
        }
    }

    printf("Check:\n");
    for (a=1;a>=0;a--) {
        for (b=1;b>=0;b--) {
            printf(" [%d][%d]:%d\n", a, b, matrice[a][b]);
        }
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

In the first loop, the modified code run through the correct indices that for a 2x2 array are (0,0),(0,1),(1,0) and (1,1).
Please note that I have also modified the `scanf` part using the correct syntax: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/).

The second loop is a simple test that what you've coded the data insertion correctly, by outputting the content of the matrix.